# mlr3 : Benchmark different features selection methods

Tags: r, feature-selection, validation, train, methodology

I have a simple question concerning my methodology.
I'm building some algorithms of machine learning to predict a binary outcome, using mlr3.
I optimized my different learners (svm, ranger, glmnet, xgboost, rpart) on the train + validation sets.
Now, I'm trying to understand the influence of the feature selection on the results (does it improve it ?).
I focused then on different methods of features selection (I started with 900 features on my native dataset):
-Pearson correlation + wilcoxon test : 14 features.
-Feature importance with xgboost: I selected the top 20 features.
-Information gain with rpart : 1 feature alone...
-Embedded method with rpart : 17 features.
-I also combined all the previous methods and selected the most picked up features (5 features)

But here is the problem :
If I compare multiple learners with these methods on the validation set, I suppose the xgboost will perform much better with the feature importance because it selected these features for this set specifically...(for example)
It is a huge bias for me...
How could I do then ? Compare the methods of feature selection on the test set directly ?